# boost thread not populating local objects passed by reference

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I have my code setup like this:

```
class Foo
{
  void doWork(std::vector<int>& to_fill)
  {
    //do some of the filling in another thread
    boost::thread thread(&Foo::workToDoInThread, this, to_fill);

    //do some filling in the main calling thread
    std::vector<int> new_to_fill;
    new_to_fill.push_back(0);     //other, similar operations

    //in case the other thread is still working, wait for it to finish
    thread.join();

    //combine the two vectors:
    to_fill.insert(to_fill.end(), new_to_fill.begin(), new_to_fill.end();

  }

  void workToDoInThread(std::vector<int>& to_fill)
  {
    to_fill.push_back(1);     //other, similar operations
  }
}
```

The problem here is that the `to_fill` vector is empty if it is checked immediately after the call to `join()`. So essentially I loose all the values that were populated by the other thread. But if I do this:

```
class Foo
{
  std::vector<int> temp_to_fill;

  void doWork(std::vector<int>& to_fill)
  {
    //do some of the filling in another thread
    boost::thread thread(&Foo::workToDoInThread, this);

    //do some filling in the main calling thread
    std::vector<int> new_to_fill;
    new_to_fill.push_back(0);     //other, similar operations

    //in case the other thread is still working, wait for it to finish
    thread.join();

    //combine the two vectors:
    to_fill.insert(to_fill.end(), new_to_fill.begin(), new_to_fill.end();
    to_fill.insert(to_fill.end(), temp_to_fill.begin(), temp_to_fill.end();

    //clear the temp vector for the next call
    temp_to_fill.clear();

  }

  void workToDoInThread()
  {
    temp_to_fill.push_back(1);     //other, similar operations
  }
}
```

This seems to work just fine. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread parameters are indeed copied by value. If you really need to pass the parameter by reference, use either `boost::ref` or `std::ref`:

```
boost::thread thread(&Foo::workToDoInThread, this, boost::ref(to_fill));
```

This creates a reference wrapper, which is still copied by value, but tracks the actual reference internally.

Comment: Wish I'd known this sooner. Sure looks more tidy then having a bunch of temporary class variables.

Comment: I was also trapped by this one for the first time. That's why I know ;)